# Reorganizing array elements in Python

Tags: python, numpy

How do I reorganize elements of `A (shape = (1,7,2))` to generate new array `A1 (shape = (1,7,2))` in order of increasing `j`? In `A[0,0]= array([0, 1])`, `j` refers to `1` in `[0,1]`.

It would be great to have something very generic so that the code can deal with when shape of `A` becomes very large, say `(1,1000,2)`.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 5],[3, 4],[4, 7],[5, 6]]])
print("A =", A.shape)
```

The desired output is

```
A1 = np.array([[[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[3, 4],[2, 5],[5, 6],[4, 7]]])
```

Comment: `np.sort(A)` The last axis is the default. Or, you could use `np.sort(A, axis=2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is defined first, then the array is sorted by order.

```
A = np.array([[[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 5],[3, 4],[4, 7],[5, 6]]])
order = A[0,:, 1].argsort()
A =np.array([A[0][order]])
print(A)
```